# How do I get this widget to display using the appendTo() function, in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code & I've tired using JQuery's appendTo() function to get this widget to display...there is something I'm missing but I'm having trouble pin-pointing it.

Here is the original code, see below:

```
var theText = new Array();
theText[0] = "David Footitt is absolutely delighted with them and the service he received.<br /><br />Regtransfers are definitely the first port of call whenever I or my colleagues are looking for a special number plate, he said.";
theText[1] = "What was Prakash Patel's experience with Regtransfers?<br /><br />Great service, always keeping us up to date with related plates, transfers done very easily and value for money.";
theText[2] = "4 MBE is one the best investments that I have made in recent years.<br /><br />Thanks to Regtransfers for making it such a simple and straightforward process. It's definitely got me thinking about others for the business.";

var links = new Array();
links[0] = 'http://www.regtransfers.co.uk/number-plates-stories/new51.asp';
links[1] = 'http://www.regtransfers.co.uk/number-plates-stories/oo08cty.asp';
links[2] = 'http://www.regtransfers.co.uk/main/stories/4mbe.asp';

var title = new Array();
title[0] = '<strong>David Footitt</strong><br />(News Transport Ltd)<br />NEW 51';
title[1] = '<strong>Prakash Patel</strong><br />(City Inter-Rent)<br />OO08 CTY';
title[2] = '<strong>Sandeep Patel</strong><br />(Ambe Medical Group)<br />4 MBE';

var images = new Array();
images[0] = '/images_new/rotatingTestimonials/new51.jpg';
images[1] = '/images_new/rotatingTestimonials/oo08cty.jpg';
images[2] = '/images_new/rotatingTestimonials/4mbe.jpg';

var j = 0
var p = theText.length;

var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

document.write('<div style="padding:3px; border:1px solid #CCC;"><div style="background-image:url(/images_new/backgrounds/grey_gradient.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:90%; padding:5px;">Satisfied Customer</div><p align="center" style="font-size:11px;">' + title[whichImage] + '</p><p align="center" style="font-size:11px;"><img src="' + images[whichImage] + '" alt="Customer Testimonials" style="width:140px" /></p><p align="left" style="font-size:11px;">' + theText[whichImage] + '</p><p align="right" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="' + links[whichImage] + '">read more ...</a></p></div>');
```

I thought if I change the last line to:

```
$('<div...long html string with the other variables').appendTo($('#rotate-testimonials'));
```

it might work. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong??

Any help is Greatly Appreciated, Thanks

Comment: what happens when you changed that  last line? have you tried firefox with firebug console on?

Comment: *"Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong??"* Not without knowing what result you're seeing, no.

Comment: @corroded - nothing displays in the DIV#rotate-testimonials, which is empty. Just tired FF with firebug console on & nothing :S

Comment: Can you put your code somewhere public? e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I'm trying to get this widget that randomly displays text, to load into a DIV called '#rotate-testimonials'. Currently it is a <script....</script> called in the HTML markup...I'm attempting to move away from that & make it Unobtrusive JavaScript

Comment: @johnhunter - http://jsfiddle.net/yrXYG/

Comment: @Nasir: I understand that, it's just that you hadn't said *how* it's not working. You have now, in a reply to corroded. (Fundamentally, your code works -- see my answer for a live example, and a couple of bits of refactoring if you're interested.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, it works, but I suspect you wanted to *replace* the `rotate-testimonials` content rather than appending (adding) to it. So the last line would be:

```
$('#rotate-testimonials').html(...long string...);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/alere)

**Edit**: You've said that what's going wrong on your end is that nothing shows up in the `DIV#rotate-testimonials`. You should have been seeing *something*, even with your original code, so here are some things to check:

1. Are you running your code before the `div#rotate-testimonials` exists in the DOM? E.g., is the script *above* the `div` and not wrapped in a [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler or similar? This is an easy-to-make mistake. The div has to exist before you can write to it, and script is run immediately. In my example above, note that everything is wrapped in a `jQuery(function($) { ... });` structure, which isn't called until the DOM is ready to be manipulated. You can do it that way, or just put your script at the very end of the page, just before your `</body>` tag.
2. Do you really have a div with `id="rotate-testimonials"`? E.g., no typos or similar, it's an `id` not a `name`, etc.
3. Do you have only *one* element or other global object with that name? (Easy way to check: Change the name to "fluglehorn" both in the `id="..."` in the markup and in the script. If it starts working, that means you have something *else* also called `rotate-testimonials` kicking around somewhere. Of course, this assumes you don't have anything called `fluglehorn` lying around...

If it's none of those things, I'm out of ideas, but hopefully comparing what you have with the working version above will help.

---

**Off-topic**: That said, a bit of refactoring can help make it easier to add entries to the testimonials, etc. Rather than parallel arrays, I'd use an array of objects, with a property for each of the bits of information (text, title, link, image). Also, you can use array and object literal notation (rather than `new Array();` and then a bunch of assignments.

Here's a version that *just* changes to array literal notation:

```
var theText = [
  "David Footitt is absolutely delighted with them and the service he received.<br /><br />Regtransfers are definitely the first port of call whenever I or my colleagues are looking for a special number plate, he said.",
  "What was Prakash Patel's experience with Regtransfers?<br /><br />Great service, always keeping us up to date with related plates, transfers done very easily and value for money.",
  "4 MBE is one the best investments that I have made in recent years.<br /><br />Thanks to Regtransfers for making it such a simple and straightforward process. It's definitely got me thinking about others for the business."
  ];

var links = [
  'http://www.regtransfers.co.uk/number-plates-stories/new51.asp',
  'http://www.regtransfers.co.uk/number-plates-stories/oo08cty.asp',
  'http://www.regtransfers.co.uk/main/stories/4mbe.asp'
  ];

var title = [
  '<strong>David Footitt</strong><br />(News Transport Ltd)<br />NEW 51',
  '<strong>Prakash Patel</strong><br />(City Inter-Rent)<br />OO08 CTY',
  '<strong>Sandeep Patel</strong><br />(Ambe Medical Group)<br />4 MBE'
  ];

var images = [
  '/images_new/rotatingTestimonials/new51.jpg',
  '/images_new/rotatingTestimonials/oo08cty.jpg',
  '/images_new/rotatingTestimonials/4mbe.jpg'
  ];

var j = 0
var p = theText.length;

var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

$('#rotate-testimonials').html(
  '<div style="padding:3px; border:1px solid #CCC;"><div style="background-image:url(/images_new/backgrounds/grey_gradient.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:90%; padding:5px;">Satisfied Customer</div><p align="center" style="font-size:11px;">' + title[whichImage] + '</p><p align="center" style="font-size:11px;"><img src="' + images[whichImage] + '" alt="Customer Testimonials" style="width:140px" /></p><p align="left" style="font-size:11px;">' + theText[whichImage] + '</p><p align="right" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="' + links[whichImage] + '">read more ...</a></p></div>');
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/alere/2)

And here's a minimally-refactored version that uses an array of objects instead:

```
var entries = [
    {   text:   "David Footitt is absolutely delighted with them " +
                "and the service he received.<br /><br />Regtransfers " +
                "are definitely the first port of call whenever I or " +
                "my colleagues are looking for a special number plate, he said.",
        link:   "http://www.regtransfers.co.uk/number-plates-stories/new51.asp",
        title:  "<strong>David Footitt</strong><br />(News Transport Ltd)<br />NEW 51",
        image:  "/images_new/rotatingTestimonials/new51.jpg"
    },
    {   text:   "What was Prakash Patel's experience with Regtransfers?<br />" +
                "<br />Great service, always keeping us up to date with related " +
                "plates, transfers done very easily and value for money.",
        link:   "http://www.regtransfers.co.uk/number-plates-stories/oo08cty.asp",
        title:  "<strong>Prakash Patel</strong><br />(City Inter-Rent)<br />OO08 CTY",
        image:  "/images_new/rotatingTestimonials/oo08cty.jpg"
    },
    {   text:   "4 MBE is one the best investments that I have made in recent " +
                "years.<br /><br />Thanks to Regtransfers for making it such a " +
                "simple and straightforward process. It's definitely got me " + 
                "thinking about others for the business.",
        link:   "http://www.regtransfers.co.uk/main/stories/4mbe.asp",
        title:  "<strong>Sandeep Patel</strong><br />(Ambe Medical Group)<br />4 MBE",
        image:  "/images_new/rotatingTestimonials/4mbe.jpg"
    }
];

var j = 0
var p = entries.length;

var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

$('#rotate-testimonials').html(
  '<div style="padding:3px; border:1px solid #CCC;"><div style="background-image:url(/images_new/backgrounds/grey_gradient.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:90%; padding:5px;">Satisfied Customer</div><p align="center" style="font-size:11px;">' + entries[whichImage].title + '</p><p align="center" style="font-size:11px;"><img src="' + entries[whichImage].image + '" alt="Customer Testimonials" style="width:140px" /></p><p align="left" style="font-size:11px;">' + entries[whichImage].text + '</p><p align="right" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="' + entries[whichImage].link + '">read more ...</a></p></div>');
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/alere/3)

You can go even further than that (and certainly a stylesheet would help that massive string at the end), but you get the idea.

Comment: nice guy! (for the live copy, and the refactoring)

Comment: @Nasir: Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery also has the basic .append() method, which should work great and reads a bit easier.

```
$('#rotate-testimonials').append('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a selector and not the text. Put in the selector for your DIV with lots of text in place of the div content itself and you should be fine

```
<div id='theDiveID'>long html string with the other variables</div>

$('#theDivID').appendTo('#rotate-testimonials');
```